# Azure app service (paas) + Storage + WordPress

Tags: wordpress, azure, storage, paas

I would like to run multiple WordPress instances using Azure Application Service and have a dedicated VM running their MySQL databases.

Let's say each Wordpress site was a gig in size (uploaded files not database) and my App Service plan comes with 50gig storage. This means I could theoretically run a max of 50 WordPress sites on that
plan.

Is it possible to link a blob storage plan to my paas plan and have all WordPress sites stored on the additional storage plan?

I know there is an outdated WordPress plugin that supposedly stores uploaded media on Azure storage plans. I'm not interested in that. I want all WordPress files stored and served from a separate storage plan.

If I was to spin up a VM running IIS I imagine I could do this by simply pointing each IIS site to each WordPress install on a storage plan data disk. Just wondering if I can do the same using Paas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically App Service is already doing this.  Your 50GB of space is in Blob Storage.  But as you suspect, you have no control over this yourself.  If you want/need that level of control, then you need to switch to a VM as you suggested.

This is exactly why the storage plugins were built, to move the uploaded media files into Blob Storage to maximize available space and improve performance.

Another way to save "local" space would be to run as a multisite if possible. Then you would only need one copy of WP and any plugins in common for the various sites.

Comment: The WordPress blob storage plugin hasn't been updated in 7 months and users are complaining about problems with it. That's a headache I want to swerve. Thanks for your clarification.